# Can't switch to microsoft account

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-account

I can't sign in to the Microsoft account in settings or Store.

This is my second install of Windows10 Home X64 on my HP Desktop

The previous install was Windows 7 X64 Home.

The fault still occurs.

When I click Microsoft account in "Choose an account" window in "Store" the window just closes. This is the same in settings when I  click "Sign in with Microsoft account instead"

Windows 10 is of no use if I can't use the store.

I have upgraded 2 other systems, 1 from Windows 8.1 and the other from Windows 7 X64 Home and both work fine.

There is nothing wrong with my Microsoft account. The fault is system specific.

How can I resolve this?